Expected number of tosses of a coin to get HHTT
lets consider the outcomes to get 2 heads followed by 2 tails: T, probability 1/2, wasted one attempt
HT, probability 1/4, wasted 2 attempts
HHH, probability 1/8, wasted one attempt
HHTH, probability 1/16, 2 attempts
HHTT probabilty 1/16
Let $x$ denote the expected rolls to get HHTT. Then, we have
$$x = \frac12(x+1) + \frac14(x+2) + \frac18(x+1) + \frac1{16}(x+2) + \frac1{16},$$
which gives the answer $x=24$. I know it must be $16$, but i am confused what is the error in my solution.
Thanks for help!

Welcome to MSE! Please consider using MathJax for typesetting mathematical expressions in your post.

Some comments:

When you roll $HHH$, you don't have to start completely over. You could use the last two $H$s to finish (e.g. $HHHHTT$) or even just the last $H$ (e.g. $HHHHHTT$).
For the last $1/16$ term, you forgot to multiply by $4$ (for the four rolls needed to get $HHTT$).



Let $N$ be the expected number of rolls until seeing $HHTT$ for the first time.
Let $N_H$ denote the expected number of additional rolls until seeing $HHTT$ for the first time given that either (a) you have rolled exactly once already, and the previous roll was $H$, or (b) the previous two rolls were $TH$.
Let $N_{HH}$ denote the expected number of additional rolls until seeing $HHTT$ for the first time given that either (a) you have rolled exactly twice already, and the previous two rolls were $HH$, or (b) the previous three rolls were $THH$.

This leads to the following system of equations.
\begin{align}
N &= \frac{1}{2} (N+1) + \frac{1}{4}(N+2) + \frac{1}{8}(N_{HH}+3) + \frac{1}{16}(N_H + 4) + \frac{1}{16} \cdot 4
\\
N_H &= \frac{1}{2}(N+1) + \frac{1}{4}(N_{HH} + 2) + \frac{1}{8}(N_H + 3) + \frac{1}{8} \cdot 3
\\
N_{HH} &= \frac{1}{2}(N_{HH}+1) + \frac{1}{4}(N_H + 2) + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 2
\end{align}
Simplifying yields
\begin{align}
4 N  - N_H- 2 N_{HH} &= 30
\\
-4 N +7N_H -2 N_{HH} &= 14
\\
- N_{H} + 2 N_{HH} &= 6
\end{align}
which leads to the solutions $N=16$, $N_H=14$, $N_{HH}=10$.

There is a very simple way of arriving at a solution for such problems using Conway's algorithm, (not to be confused with the Doomsday algorithm) which successively assigns Y or N to the string if entries are identical starting from left and ending at right, or not. of $HHTT$

length $1$: N, H  left, T  right
length $2$: N, HH  left, TT  right
length $3$: N, HHT  left, HTT  right
length $4$: Y, HHTT  both left and right

The # of tosses needed would be  $\sum 2^L (L=\;length)$ for lengths having a $Y$
so here the answer would directly flow out as $2^4=16$
